# Using higher level reducer alongside combined lower level reducers

Tags: redux, reducers

I have a react/redux app with store set up like this:

```
interface AppState {
  substateA: SubstateA;
  substateB: SubstateB;
}
```

And two reducers managing their individual states:

```
const reducer = combineReducers<AppState>({
    substateA: reducerA,
    substateb: reducerB,
});
```

What I would like to do as add a reducer that manages whole state additionally to those 2 reducers. How can I do that or is there other better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer is simply a function that takes state and an action and returns a new state object.

`combineReducers` returns a reducer which calls each of your reducers with only their slice of the state.

Have a play with something like this.. you may want it to run the combined reducers first, or your global state reducer first, depending on what you are doing.

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers<AppState>({
  substateA: reducerA,
  substateb: reducerB,
});

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  state = reducerC(state, action);
  return combinedReducer(state, action);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, both reducers are getting called now but I have a different problem, which is not directly related. I am saving instances of classes with method into the store and it looks like `this` points to wrong object when a method is called.

Comment: hmm, yeh, don't do that. Only plain objects/arrays/strings should go in the store.

Comment: And do you have any suggestion how to do that any other way? I basically have in store saved bunch of object under unique Id's that all derive from common class and have their own `serialize` method. And I would like to be able to just serialize all the objects (they create a tree structure and refer to each other by Ids)

Comment: re non-serializable items in the store.. https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state, though you've already discovered an issue. organizing nested data.. https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state basically you should be aiming to serialize and normalize the data and building a set of selectors to pull the data you need from the store. Normailizing he data makes things much simpler when it comes to creating reducers to manage the store data

Comment: Ok but where should I put my custom serialization methods? Would they maybe work as static methods that accept the plain object from store as an argument? How would I then dynamically dispatch to correct derived type's implementation? All the classes have unique string literal.

Comment: yeh, you could build it into a layer that sits over the selectors, I guess. I don't know what you need to achieve, so can't really advise. I stick with plain objects myself. Don't recall having a need for class objects. Sorry, serialization of the class objects you'd build into the actions flow somehow. But it really doesn't fit with the way Redux works. You may want to look into Mobx which is much more class based.